# Fire trigger of alt+Shift on focus of textbox in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, c#-4.0

I want to fire the trigger of alt+shift automatically on focus of textbox in asp.net.
 Is it possible and how??

Comment: why you want to fire alt+shift automatically?

Comment: I want to type in Hindi language in Textbox and it is possible when i press alt+shift but i do not want to press the alt+shift via keyboard ..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function clickevent()
{                
     var e = $.Event("keydown");
     e.which = 16;
     e.keyCode = 16;
     $(document).trigger(e);       
}
```

Comment: @user3176085 var ee = $.Event("keydown");
         ee.which = shiftkeycode;
         ee.keyCode = shiftkeycode;
         $(document).trigger(ee);

Comment: @user3176085 please accept answer if useful for you by green checking icon.

Comment: function clickevent() {
            var e = $.Event("keydown");
            e.which = 16;
            e.keyCode = 16;
            $(document).trigger(e);
            var e1 = $.Event("keydown");
            e1.which = 18;
            e1.keyCode = 18;

            $(document).trigger(e1);

            alert('kjdhsfk');
//            $(document).on('foo', function (event) {
//                $(document).trigger(e);
//                $(document).trigger(e1);
//            });
                }